# Detecting the angle of a corner using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, corner-detection

I have the following image of a corner:

[image: original]

I'm trying to get the angle of the white corner, i.e. the following:

[image: expected result]

So I went through the obvious route to remove the noise

1. Converted the image to grayscale
2. Added some gaussian blur
3. Applied threshold

And the result was as follows:

[image: after threshold]

Since I want the angle, I needed the lines that make-up this corner, so, of course, I ran canny + hough lines, but here lies the problem, I keep getting multiple false lines using Hough and I have no idea how to filter them out:

[image: after Hough Transform]

Is there's any known way to get the confidence of each line so I can only get the correct vertical+horizontal parts of the corner?

Comment: Maybe skeletonise first...

Comment: Do you have some other examples please?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47834583/2571705) might help.

Comment: Wasn't this successfully answered? Can you Accept any of the answers below?

Comment: Same question, new year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is an approach without `cv::HoughLines()`**: on the binary image, execute a function to detect the most distant pixel from the center of the image towards a specific direction (left, right, top, bottom). This function returns the following pixels, drawn in the image below in red, green and blue:

```
Left:  [21, 35]
Top:   [43, 0]
Right: [63, 35]
```

[image]

From these 3 points you have a couple of options to detect the angle:

- Discard one of the points and compute the angle between the other 2;
- Figure out which one is the center point and compute the angle between all 3 of them;

The source code below figures out which one is closest to the center of the image and computes the angle from all the 3 points using the `atan2()` method.

Running the example with the binary image outputs:

```
Angle: 57.8477 (degrees)
```

**Seems legit!**

There's a few improvements you can do from here on to improve the accuracy of the angle. One of them is to skeletonize the binary image and make those lines really thin.

**Source code**:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>    
#include <iostream>    

enum imgEdge {
    LEFT = 0,
    RIGHT = 1,
    TOP = 2,
    BOTTOM = 3
};

// Find the most distant pixel from the center in a particular direction
cv::Point mostDistantPixel(const cv::Mat& input, const imgEdge& edge)
{
    if (edge < 0 || edge > 3)
    {
        std::cout << "!!! mostDistantPixel() invalid side" << std::endl;
        return cv::Point();
    }

    if (input.channels() > 1)
    {
        std::cout << "!!! mostDistantPixel() only single channel img is supported" << std::endl;
        return cv::Point();
    }

    cv::Point mostDistant(-1,-1);
    for (int r = 0; r < input.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < input.cols; c++)
        {
            // Examine pure white pixels only (row, col)
            if (input.at<uchar>(r,c) == 255)
            {
                switch (edge)
                {
                    case imgEdge::LEFT:
                         if (c <= mostDistant.x || mostDistant == cv::Point(-1, -1))
                             mostDistant = cv::Point(c, r);
                    break;

                    case imgEdge::RIGHT:
                         if (c >= mostDistant.x || mostDistant == cv::Point(-1, -1))
                             mostDistant = cv::Point(c, r);
                    break;

                    case imgEdge::TOP:
                         if (r <= mostDistant.y || mostDistant == cv::Point(-1, -1))
                             mostDistant = cv::Point(c, r);
                    break;

                    case imgEdge::BOTTOM:
                         if (r >= mostDistant.y || mostDistant == cv::Point(-1, -1))
                             mostDistant = cv::Point(c, r);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return mostDistant;
}

// Eucledian distance between 2 points
unsigned int distance(const cv::Point& a, const cv::Point& b)
{
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(b.x-a.x, 2) + std::pow(b.y-a.y, 2));
}

// Compute the angle between 3 points (degrees)
double calcAngle(const cv::Point& center, const cv::Point& point, const cv::Point& base)
{
    /* Compute the angle between the center, a point and it's base (starting point for the angle computation)
     *
     *      %
     *    *   *         @ = center
     *   *  @  #        # = base (origin)
     *    *   *         % = point
     *      *           From # to %, there are 90 degrees
     */

    double angle = std::atan2(point.y - center.y, point.x - center.x) * 180 / 3.141592;
    angle = (angle < 0) ? (360 + angle) : angle;
    return (360 - angle);
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("corner.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "!!! imread()" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Find the left-most, right-most and top-most pixel
    cv::Point leftPix = mostDistantPixel(img, imgEdge::LEFT);
    std::cout <<  "Left: " << leftPix << std::endl;

    cv::Point topPix = mostDistantPixel(img, imgEdge::TOP);
    std::cout <<  "Top: " << topPix << std::endl;

    cv::Point rightPix = mostDistantPixel(img, imgEdge::RIGHT);
    std::cout <<  "Right: " << rightPix << std::endl;

    // Draw pixels for debugging purposes
//    cv::Mat colored;
//    cv::cvtColor(img, colored, CV_GRAY2BGR);
//    cv::circle(colored, leftPix, 2, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), cv::FILLED);     // red
//    cv::circle(colored, topPix, 2, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), cv::FILLED);      // green
//    cv::circle(colored, rightPix, 2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), cv::FILLED);    // blue
//    cv::imwrite("points.png", colored);

    // Find the pivot point: which of them is closest to the center
    cv::Point center(img.cols/2, img.rows/2);
    unsigned int leftDistance = distance(center, leftPix);
    unsigned int rightDistance = distance(center, rightPix);
    unsigned int topDistance = distance(center, topPix);

    // This part needs a lot more testing and refinement
    double angle = 0;
    if (leftDistance <= rightDistance &&  leftDistance <= topDistance)
        angle = calcAngle(leftPix, topPix, rightPix);   // looks good
    else if (rightDistance <= leftDistance &&  rightDistance <= topDistance)
        angle = calcAngle(rightPix, leftPix, topPix);   // needs testing
    else
        angle = calcAngle(topPix, leftPix, rightPix);   // needs testing

    std::cout <<  "Angle: " << angle << " (degrees)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the parameters passed to the Hough function.

I assume you use something like

```
HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 0, 0 );
```

Try to play with the parameters `rho`, `theta` and `threshold`, your resolution could be too fine.

[Hough OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)

[Hough Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html)

Comment: I'm already playing with the parameters. I'm running a while loop which increases the threshold until only 3-4 lines are left, but sometimes the function goes from 7 lines to 1 lines so I must filter the excessive 6 lines

Comment: The duplicate lines in your example are quite similar, you could also just take the average of them... :)

Comment: I can't be sure they will always be similar. I need a way to group them first and then take the average of each group