# how to make my code identify the difference between 2 circles (2 circles one filled with white and one with black) using python and pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have 2 images,

1- White circle with black stroke

2- Black circle with black stroke

I want to compare both images and identify that both have the same circle but with different filling 
I should only use python & pillow

I have already tried several methods like Edge Detection, but whenever I try to reform the picture for edge detection the new image appear as empty

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

# Load image:
input_image = Image.open("input.png")
input_pixels = input_image.load()
width, height = input_image.width, input_image.height

# Create output image
output_image = Image.new("RGB", input_image.size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output_image)

# Convert to grayscale
intensity = np.zeros((width, height))
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        intensity[x, y] = sum(input_pixels[x, y]) / 3

# Compute convolution between intensity and kernels
for x in range(1, input_image.width - 1):
    for y in range(1, input_image.height - 1):
        magx = intensity[x + 1, y] - intensity[x - 1, y]
        magy = intensity[x, y + 1] - intensity[x, y - 1]

        # Draw in black and white the magnitude
        color = int(sqrt(magx**2 + magy**2))
        draw.point((x, y), (color, color, color))

output_image.save("edge.png")
```

expected result that the both pictures will be greyscaled with only the circle edges marked in white

actual result empty black image (as if it couldnt see the edges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, If all you want is Edge Detection in an image, then you can try using [**Sobel Operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) or its equivalents.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

image = Image.open(r"Circle.png").convert("RGB")
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
image.save(r"ED_Circle.png")
```

The above code takes in an input image, converts it into **RGB** mode (certain images have `P` mode, which doesn't allows edge detection, therefore converting to RGB). Then finds edges in it via `image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)`.

Sample Input Image (Black border with black circle):-

[image]

Output after processing through python program:-

[image]

Sample Image 2 (white circle with black border):-

[image]

Output after processing through python program:-

[image]

In the above sample, both the input images were of the same size and the circles in them were also of the same dimensions, the only difference between the two was that, one had a white circle inside a black border, and the other had a black circle inside black border.

Since the circles were of same dimensions, passing them through the edge detection process gave us same results.

**NOTE:-**

- In the question, you wanted circle edges in white, and the rest of
  part in greyscale. Which isn't the best choice for edge detection.
  White and Black are inverse of each other, therefore edges could be
  easily identified if the sample space of the image consists of these
  two colors. Even then, if you want greyscale instead of black, then you can simple change each black pixel of the image to a grey one, or something that meets your needs
- The results of above edge detection are same because the size of the
  border is negligible. If the border is wider (a stroke), then when
  the process is done on a white circle with black border, the edge
  detection will create more then one white border. You can get through
  that problem, by making the program ignore the inner edges and only
  taking into account the outermost ones.

Comment: I will try that today and feed you back 
I guess that the error in my method was not converting them to RGB ^^

Thank you for the lovely explanation

Comment: do you know a way to ignore the filling of the circle if its stripped (1 white circle ) ( 1 stripped circle) 

I wanna get the edge of the outer frame only but ignores whats inside

Comment: @HussienEl-Sawy [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777585/detecting-outer-most-edge-of-image-and-plotting-based-on-it/47820911#47820911) will definitely guide you to what you are trying to achieve. Even though it's in `cv2`, but still you can create its PIL equivalent pretty easily